# NodeJS app on Glitch is not connecting to remote SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am getting this error while connecting to a SQL Server instance. I am running this on `https://glitch.com/` hosting:

> Failed to connect to ***.***.net:1433 - self signed certificate

Code:

app.get("/api/products", function(req, res) {
getProducts();

function getProducts() {
var dbConfig = {
user: "dbUser",
password: "dbPassword",
server: "server address",
database: "dbName",
};

```
var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
dbConn
  .connect()
  .then(function() {
    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
    request
      .query("select top 20 * from product")
      .then(function(resp) {
        res.send(resp);
        dbConn.close();
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        res.send(err);
        dbConn.close();
      });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    res.send(err);
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `dbConfig.options.trustServerCertificate: true` yet?

Comment: unction getProducts() {
    var dbConfig = {
      user: "user",
      password: "password",
      server: "server",
      database: "dbName",
      options: {
  trustServerCertificate: true
   },

landed in an error . No luck

Comment: Landed an error? What error? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69822751/edit) your question with this new information - as text.

Answer (score 1):

Please check how you edited the `trustServerCertificate: true` setting into your `dbConfig`.

Here's an example that replicates the error from your question using Docker containers for `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` and `node:16`:

```js
//server.js
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
  getProducts();
  function getProducts() {
    var dbConfig = {
      user: "sa",
      password: "StrongPassw0rd",
      server: "foo-db",
      database: "msdb"
    };
    var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    dbConn
      .connect()
      .then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
        request
          .query("select top 1 object_id, name from sys.tables order by name")
          .then(function (resp) {
            res.send(resp.recordset);
            dbConn.close();
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            res.send(err);
            dbConn.close();
          });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        res.send(err);
      });
  }
});

const UTC_NOW = () => (new Date()).toISOString();
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const PORT = 80;
app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`${UTC_NOW()} Listening on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Opening a web browser to http://localhost/api/products yields the response:

```json
{
    "code": "ESOCKET",
    "originalError": {
        "message": "Failed to connect to foo-db:1433 - self signed certificate",
        "code": "ESOCKET"
    },
    "name": "ConnectionError"
}
```

If we use the following dbConfig instead:

```js
    var dbConfig = {
      user: "sa",
      password: "StrongPassw0rd",
      server: "foo-db",
      database: "msdb",
      options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true
      }
    };
```

Then the web browser response is:

```json
[
    {
        "object_id": 1561772621,
        "name": "autoadmin_managed_databases"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you , Sorted issue